# PHP imap_fetchbody() function does not return when section set to 1.2

Tags: php, email, imap, php-imap

### Background

I am running the following code to retrieve emails using the [IMAP PHP extension](http://php.net/manual/en/book.imap.php):

```
<?php
    /* connect to gmail */
    $hostname = '{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl}INBOX';
    $username = 'blah@gmail.com';
    $password = 'blah';

    $inbox = imap_open($hostname,$username,$password);

    $emails = imap_search($inbox,'ALL');

    if ($emails) {
        foreach($emails as $emailNumber) {
            $overview = imap_fetch_overview($inbox,$emailNumber,0);
            $message = imap_fetchbody($inbox,$emailNumber,"1");

            echo $overview[0]->from;
            echo $message;

        }
    }
    imap_close($inbox);
?>
```

### Question

Having the `imap_fetchbody()` `section` argument set to `1`, I am receiving the full email including headers and HTML. http://pastebin.com/np84rG7r

However, when changing the argument to `1.2` in order to identify the message as HTML, It returns nothing.

Why is this happening?

### Update

I've made this little snippet of code to do the work manually until I can find out why it's not working:

```
$message = imap_fetchbody($inbox,$emailNumber,"1.1.1");
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($message);
$message = trim($doc->getElementsByTagName("td")->item(0)->nodeValue);
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what do you get when you use 1.1?

Comment: @PatrickQ Here ya go... http://pastebin.com/bu6QrgrW

Comment: Using `1.2` for HTML assumes that the email also contains a plaintext section before the HTML.  The email in your example does not, which is why `1.1` is returning the HTML.

Comment: The headers above the HTML are in plaintext aren't they?

Comment: There is no set order for which body sections occur when, or even if they need to be present. You should be inspecting the section headers, particularly `Content-Type:`.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately `imap_fetchbody`'s part number depends whether your mail has html or not, and whether it has any attachment. When you have a plain text mail, then you need to use `1` instead of `1.2`.

To read the complete tragedy I recommend https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imap-fetchbody.php#89002

A cheesy way to make sure that you always get the body content is actually

```
$message = imap_fetchbody($inbox,$emailNumber,1.2);
if(empty($bodyText)){
    $message = imap_fetchbody($inbox,$emailNumber,1);
}
```